# Net Core Worker Service sending an exception to main thread?

Tags: c#, background-task, .net-core-3.0

I need to return Exit Code -1 from Main if retries failed so (Kubernetes) handle it, I try throwing an exception (`Task.FromException`) from `ExecuteAsync` but the method signature will change and it is not allowed to change from `Task` to `Task<T>`. How can I raised a `Environment.Exit(-1)` to the main thread? or cancellation to main thread so I can return an exit code -1 from there

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    int tries = 0;
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested && tries <= _tryOuts)
    {
        try
        {
                ...
                tries++;
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                ...
                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogError(response.Message, DateTimeOffset.Now);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
        }
        _logger.LogDebug("Worker next iteration in milliseconds {0}", _timeBetweenTryOuts);
        await Task.Delay(_timeBetweenTryOuts, stoppingToken);
    }
    _hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
}
```

Comment: It looks like a batch process that eventually terminates even if stopToken is not flagged.  You might as well run it in the main thread  or inside Task.Run()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting topic. I created PoC but in Asp .NET Core 2.1(I don't have now version 3), and I'm able to return other exit code using:

```
Environment.ExitCode
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exitcode?view=netcore-3.0

So, try do something like:

```
Environment.ExitCode = -1;
_hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
```

Comment: I was having problems getting the application to stop.  The "IHostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication()" worked for me in .NET 5.